# How will changing 1K block size in a fixed block size file system to 2K affect disk throughput/utilization

Tags: file, operating-system, filesystems

As per my understanding if we change 1K block size in a fixed block size file system
to 2K it will lead to **better disk throughput but poorer disk space utilization.** 
As now the file blocks are large and so disk space utilization could be poor since 
now the last nonempty block could have approx 2K space. Whereas when it was 
1K the last nonempty block could have approx 1K space. 
So there is poor disk utilization. But now the same file that was stored
in say, 100 blocks could now be stored in 50 blocks. and so read/write will be faster.

Is that correct reasoning?

Answer (score 0):

I think your reasoning is sound for most cases, but there is an edge case where larger block sizes may cause lower throughput.

Consider what happens when you have a system with many small files, and you want to read all those small files. Small files implies that these files do not use the entire 2K block size, but a block must be read in its entirety.  So, if you have a million 1K files, and each file uses half of a block, then half of the time doing IO is wasted reading parts of the block that were garbage.